# What is the best way to tell MongoDB has started?

Tags: mongodb

I have some automated tests that I run in order to test a MongoDB-related library. In order to do that, I start a Mongo server with a temporary data directory and on an ephemeral port, connect to it, and run some tests.

This leads to a race condition, obviously. So in my first version of these tests, I paused for a fixed amount of time and waited to make sure `mongod` had time to start before the tests began.

This was frustrating (and inefficient), so I decided to monitor the standard output and wait for a line on `mongod`'s standard output stream matching the regular expression:

```
/\[initandlisten\] waiting for connections/
```

This got it working. So good, then I prepared to circle back and try to find a more robust way to do it. I recalled that a Java library called "embedmongo" ran MongoDB-based tests, and figured it must solve the problem. And it does this ([GitHub](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/468a36cc58885e5646bd41c0b446fdd23521ef54/src/main/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/AbstractMongoProcess.java)):

```
protected String successMessage() {
    return "waiting for connections on port";
}
```

... and uses that to figure out whether the process has started correctly.

So, are we right? Is examining the `mongod` process output log (is it ever internationalized? could the wording of the message ever change?) the very best way to do this? Or is there something more robust that we're both missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we do in a similar scenario is:

- Try to connect to the configured port (simply new Socket(host, port)) in a loop until it works (10 ms delay) - this ensures, that the mongo client, which starts an internal monitoring thread, does not throw exceptions due to "connection refused"
- Connect to the mongodb and *query* something. This is important, as all mongo client objects are lazy init. (Simple listDatabaseNames() on the client is enough, but make sure to actually *read* the result.)
- All the time, check the process for not being terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a small `untilMongod` command which does just that, which you can use in bash scripting: https://github.com/FGM/untilMongod

Includes a bash + Node.JS example use case.